# Towers of Hanoi in OCaml

Tags: list, recursion, ocaml, tuples, towers-of-hanoi

I am a beginner OCaml programmer trying to make a function to solve the towers of hanoi problem in OCaml in the solution is represented by a list of moves in which a "move" is stored in a tuple of the form (startPeg, endPeg).

This is what I have so far:

```
type peg = A | B | C
type move = peg * peg


let towers (m : int) : (move list) =
  let rec solve n a b c = match n with
  |0 -> []
  |_ -> (solve (n-1) a c b) :: (a,b) :: (solve (n-1) c b a) in
  solve m A B C
```

I am getting the error:

File "induction.ml", line 8, characters 8-27:
Error: This expression has type 'a list
       but an expression was expected of type 'a
       The type variable 'a occurs inside 'a list

and am not sure how to fix it. 
Can anyone help me correct my error? Thanks

Answer (score 7):

The operator `::` adds an element to the head of a list. You're using it to concatenate lists. Your code will compile if you change the first `::` to the list concatenation operator `@`.

```
type peg = A | B | C
type move = peg * peg


let towers (m : int) : (move list) =
  let rec solve n a b c = match n with
  |0 -> []
  |_ -> (solve (n-1) a c b) @ (a,b) :: (solve (n-1) c b a) in
  solve m A B C
```

I don't know whether the resulting code is correct, but I hope this gets you going again.

Comment: would be nice to close the topic.